# Running cfx program for Firefox Add-on SDK on Windows

Tags: python, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have downloaded Add-on SDK and executed *activate*.
Python 2.7 is installed. PATH variable is configured properly and py files can run from anywhere.
However, when i am trying to execute *cfx* (from Far command prompt, using the full path), i get the message: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command. How do i make it run?

Comment: what's a Far command prompt?

Comment: I'm using FAR file manager for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this:

```
python c:\path\to\addon-sdk\bin\cfx -h
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Comments suck for something that is better expressed over multiple lines.

Comment: "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command" pretty much says that your answer definitely won't work

Comment: not necessarily. He reports that Python is installed correctly. There could be an issue where his console can find python, but the cfx script cannot.

Comment: Wouldn't the cfx script run inside the console use the exact same %PATH% that the console itself uses? It's a user-global environment variable

Comment: Thanks canuckistani, i tried your suggestion and it ran as it is supposed to. I'd like to add that after this when i run _cfx_ i don't get the same error but the following: `python: can't open file '\bin\cfx': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Anyway, now i have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Python 2.6 instead of Python 2.7. When i tried with Python 2.7 i got also the same error. Then i removed Python 2.7 and installed Python 2.6. And all worked finely.

Answer (score 0):

This is due a cfx bug, I had the exact same problem. You can fix it by setting the path manually as explained here:

[Error Installing Firefox Addon SDK Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872082/error-installing-firefox-addon-sdk-python)

Ayham Alkasir's answer

---

You can also install cygwin and follow the 'linux' install instructions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation
and your problem is gone.

(you need python installed in cygwin)

PRO TIP:
if you use cygwin install also wget and you can use this script to autoinstall the app for testing purposes:

```
#while true ; do cfx xpi ; wget --post-file=autobot.xpi http://localhost:8001/ ; sleep 10 ; done
```

along with this extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/

as stated here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started

Answer (score 0):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#app_exe) says, when a process is started with ShellExecuteEx (as contrary to CreateProcess I presume), it is sought in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths* as well.

I noticed similar thing, **python** from Far command prompt started python, when put into .cmd file it reported 'python' is not recognized as an internal etc. That is I had python path entry in the registry (pointing to C:\Python26\Python.exe), but not in the PATH environment.

Registry contains paths to individual applications rather than folders, so I could not start **pythonw** from Far command prompt though it lies in the same directory as python.